# Issue with vim mousemodel

Tags: vim

Recently I came across a feature of `gvim`. When I press `shift` and click on a word the words get highlighted similar to `Notepad++` (I am aware of * or #).

But if I put in my `.vimrc`

```
set mousemodel=popup
```

This behavior strangely stops. Anybody encountered this?

using

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 29 2013 13:30:15)
```

Comment: Hehe http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/1um8xu/issue_with_vim_mousemodel/

Answer (score 2):

This is actually by design according to `:h mousemodel`:

```
                        *'mousemodel'* *'mousem'*
'mousemodel' 'mousem'   string  (default "extend", "popup" for MS-DOS and Win32)
            global
            {not in Vi}
    Sets the model to use for the mouse.  The name mostly specifies what
    the right mouse button is used for:
       extend   Right mouse button extends a selection.  This works
            like in an xterm.
       popup    Right mouse button pops up a menu.  The shifted left
            mouse button extends a selection.  This works like
            with Microsoft Windows.
(...)
    Overview of what button does what for each model:
    mouse           extend      popup(_setpos) ~
    left click      place cursor    place cursor
    left drag       start selection start selection
    shift-left      search word     extend selection
    right click     extend selection    popup menu (place cursor)
    right drag      extend selection    -
    middle click        paste       paste
```

Basically, popup simulates mouse behavior in a typical Windows application, and Windows applications don't highlight words by shift-clicking.

On a normal Windows application, highlighting a single word is done by *double-clicking*. I am not entirely sure if the popup model is responsible for that action as well, or if it happens elsewhere, but it should be easy enough for you to test.